# Suggested attire to wear for European trip in September

Tags: europe, weather-and-climate

I plan to visit Europe from September 16 to October 2 (This year). I am visiting Germany (Berlin), Czech Republic (Prague), France (Paris) and UK (London).

What's the ideal dress to wear? I am used to moderate climates in India (Around 30 degree Celsius).

Comment: Good you specified. Your "moderate" is my "unpleasantly hot".

Comment: Whatever answer you get consider throwing an extra layer on top just in case.

Comment: Don't focus too much on past weather, it has become crazy. The lesson I learned from my last two vacations: When going to a cold country (Iceland, Ireland), be sure to bring enough T-shirts :) . Both times, I brought home a bunch of unworn warm clothes because I happened to travel during a heat wave...

Comment: 30C sounds moderate to me. I'm in the U.S. in a location where it is currently (11 AM on September 6) 29C with a forecasted high of 33C.

Comment: @shoover All year round? Personally, I think if you want AC then it shouldn't really count as moderate anymore.

Comment: 30 is hot, 20 is nice, 10 is chilly, 0 is ice.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use layers to have more flexibility **and expect rain**. Even if both places are quite diverse, Northern Europe is on the whole colder than India so you will need warm clothes.

At the same time, you chose a time when you might still encounter nice days (that means close to 20°C, not 30°C) but cannot rule out cold nights or bad weather you wouldn't expect in the heart of summer. Freezing or snow are very unlikely. That's why a rain jacket on top of 2-3 layers (say a shirt and a fleece or wool sweater) is better than a thick winter coat.

Comment: And don't forget waterproof shoes! Think (summer) hiking shoes. Winter shoes are not needed at this time of the year (but pack warm socks just in case).

Comment: @ales I have never worn waterproof shoes for just general city travel. You’re far better off with a good umbrella which will easily keep the bulk of the rain off you in non-tropical climates.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek Maybe waterproof shoes are overkill (I don't wear them either) but surely the main risk are puddles not direct hits from the rain? I never found umbrellas very useful anywhere, wind in particular makes them impractical.

Comment: @Relaxed The main risk are indeed the puddles, but water directly falling in the rain as well and umbrellas are extremely useful. I wear them even for easy hiking (e.g. biological field trips) and even for moving around our caving hut in 1800 m in Austrian Alps they are very handy. Most of the time it is not that windy. In northern UK or Ireland it is more difficult but in Central Europe an umbrella is most often fine.

Comment: YMMV, but I think that waterproof shoes are absolutely NOT overkill - rubber boots, yes, but not the ones @ales mentioned. While I love umbrellas for keeping off rain of the upper body, they often fail when it comes to keeping rain off my shoes, e.g. when it's a little windy. Plus, I pick up a lot of water from the ground. If I walk around a city in the rain with non-waterproof shoes it takes somewhere between 15 and 45 minutes before my feet are wet, and walking around with wet feet is not my idea of fun...

Comment: Important to add: Warm days are still a possibility at this time of year, but the nights will definitely be cool/cold.

Comment: @Sabine Yeah, definitely. I would favor leather shoes over sandals or anything made of light fabric. But not necessarily boots or hiking shoes designed to allow water up to the ankles (which is what I imagined when reading the first comment).

Comment: I usually wear some Adidas running shoes for errands around the city and they are terrible in rain. A few steps on wet surface (not puddles!) and my socks will get wet. An umbrella won't protect your feet when walking in the rain. Longer walks will definitely be an issue without waterproof shoes. Light hiking shoes are the best option in my option.

Comment: @ales Are you really talking about waterproof or just water resistant? Waterproof shoes and material are rather exotic and expensive (most hiking boots aren't) and seem like overkill (I really only wear those for long hikes through deep snow in winter). A normal leather shoe (possibly with normal goretex) seems a more sensible choice for city travel and will be fine if you don't jump into deep puddles. This is probably more a question of terminology than an actual disagreement though.

Comment: @Voo Yes, water resistant will be OK, which is what most summer/light hiking shoes actually are (various *Tex trademarks). Sorry if I used the wrong terminology.

Comment: Also, a cool average temperature combined with high humidity can feel a lot cooler than an equivalent dry temp. E.g. London at the start of October could have temp of ~15C but with humidity >80%

Answer (score 15):

Even when it is hot for the locals, for you it will feel cold.

Bring what you wear in places with the airconditioning set too cold and expect to layer up over that.

A friend from a similar climate takes thin silk pyamas and wears those under normal street clothes.

Also bring a waterproof jacket or buy one locally as rain with wind is likely in most of your destinations and umbrellas do not work well in that weather.

As for styles, anything you like and is decent is acceptable.
If you think it is warm enough for T-shirt and casual shorts, you are welcome to wear those as a tourist. On the other hand, if you are a shirt, tie and jacket guy, those are also acceptable for a tourist.
Most will be somewhere in between, T-shirt, sweater and jeans or shirt and slacks but without tie and jacket.
Do not feel you need to wear any style or fashion, be yourself in your clothing, all is acceptable.

Answer (score 11):

That depends on the actual places you visit (Mt Blanc vs. Corsica), the time of the day and your own sensitivity. [How can one find out how many days per year a city x experiences a temperature of less than y degrees at time z of the day?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168494/1810) addresses the first two dependencies.

Wikipedia also has a nice summary for many cities and areas, [e.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris#Climate) :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Something like a breathable rain jacket for general wear.  These are typically light enough to be worn all the time and if you get something loose fitting you can put a layer or two under them.  The ones sold in shops with hiking gear are a good choice and they often have plenty of zipped pockets !  Some of them also come with a detachable inner flannel lining, almost like a second jacket, that attaches to internal zips.  Can be very nice in colder weather.

Can be quite windy and wind chill can be a shock if you're not used to it, so consider gloves.  A woolen scarf is a useful extra in a backpack.

Water-resistant foot wear if possible, but many soft shoes now are already "good enough" unless you're hiking or in seriously stormy weather.

You might want gloves. There can be quite a "bite" in the wind (wind chill) and you might find it a shock to the system given your home.

Avoid umbrellas.  They're a nuisance to other people and won't stop you getting wet, while also being a nuisance to carry.  The wind can also make them an absolute pain to use.  More trouble than they're worth.  A good jacket will do much better.

You can get breathable tops which are a good choice for walk around.  I've generally found jeans fine for walking around Ireland (similar to the UK) all year, unless you're doing serious hiking.  They'll manage OK with rain, but may get a little wet.  Cheap jeans are also things you don't need to worry about getting dirty or damaged.

Make sure your backpack or over-the-shoulder bag is a good water resistant one and/or make sure you have some plastic bags to wrap the contents in.  I typically fold up a couple of plastic carry bags and a couple of large zip-lock bags inside my own bag - very handy.

There is no such thing as "enough" zipped pockets.  I speak as a person who liked to do street photography.

Enjoy.

Comment: Once you get good activity trousers you will learn how poorly jeans work for hiking, too warm in hot weather, not warm enough in cold weather and soaking up water.

Comment: -1 Umbrellas are extremely useful. Mine does not leave my every day backpack. Sometimes it is the only thing inside (and the wallet). You will get wet on a jacket, will get wet trousers, wet backpack or suitcace and even a the wet rainproof jacket is not that breathable any more.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I gave up on umbrellas decades ago as (in Ireland) the wind makes them close to torture to use and something of a hazard for other people.  A personal gripe is people walking about with umbrellas at my head height which are hard to dodge in crowded streets and people rarely raise them high enough to avoid other people.  I'm not sure what rain gear you use but only the cheapest non-breathable junk has been a problem for me in Ireland or old gear when the water resistant seams start to fail.  YMMV of course and I can only give my own experience.

Comment: I use a Gore-Tex jacket by Berghaus, but no fabric can really breathe when water flows on the outer side. The suggested trip mainly concerns Central Europe and that is much less exposed to zonal wind coming from the Atlantic Ocran. That is even true for London (I lived in Southampton).

Comment: +1 for avoid umbrellas… but -1 for suggesting jeans are good in rain. They're the worst thing you can wear in rain. They take the longest to dry & if you're already suffering from what you'd consider 'cold' if you're used to 30°, then at 18 or 20 you'll be freezing.

Comment: +1 to avoid umbrellas.  Being caught in the rain wearing jeans isn't the end of the world but some sort of hiking trousers would be a lot better.  As Tetsujin said, once they get wet they stay wet.  The main point to take is that you can't be certain you won't get caught out by an unexpected rain shower so your plan should account for that.

Comment: @EricNolan I agree that hiking gear is needed for hiking, however I think if someone is on walkabout in a city or town they typically won't have an issue with jeans.  I'm working on the assumption the OP is not hiking and given they're from India I doubt Europe's rain holds much fear for them beyond the cold (which isn't a trivial consideration, mind you - don't get wet and stay that way in cold and windy weather).

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine You miss my point completely.  The sort of trousers used for hiking, and lots of other activities, are not necessary for walking around a city however if you get wet (which is likely at this time of year) they will be a lot better than jeans.  India does get a lot of rain, however I have met plenty of people from India who assumed that because it was sunny and dry in the morning it would remain that way all day and that is not a good assumption in northern Europe.  It would be better to dress in a way that would be suitable if it rains.

Answer (score -1):

Such questions are usually answered with historical climate data - which became quite useless with recent years climate change. You might have days as cold as 5°c and as hot as 30°c. So bring a multitude of options.

Comment: In the past those extremes did also happen. Historical data can only give an indication on what to expect, never absolute predictions.

Answer (score -2):

I've been amused watching F1 this year and listening to the commentators complaining about "scorching hot temperatures" around Europe. They're no worse than they were when I was there 3 years ago, and were far more comfortable (especially when coupled with the lower humidity) than we were used to at home (Midwest USA).

Look at the expected temps during your trip and prepare for how *you* would dress for those temps. Then, prepare for hotter and colder days as well.

The general advice is to plan to wear layers. A t-shirt can be topped with a long-sleeve shirt, then a sweatshirt or sweater added over that. You can add a rain coat to any of those layers to keep the rain off (of course), but to also add a layer of warmth and wind resistance.

While it's awkward to layer up over a pair of shorts (short trousers), bringing a pair of long pants/trousers is a good idea, just in case the weather turns chilly. There are options for "convertible" pants, where the legs will zip off leaving you with shorts, if you really want all the options.

With planning, *one* extra "warm" layer will suffice for the entire trip - you can wear the same sweater/sweatshirt several times with something clean underneath it, so it shouldn't add significantly to the bulk you're packing for your trip. Also, you'll be in different cities, so who cares if you wear the same outfit more than once - odds are good nobody will ever know.

Comment: good for your that you're used to high temperature. no need to be insensitive about it, though.

Comment: Not sure how being "amused" by something is insensitive. However, you'll probably consider this remark "insensitive", too. Sigh...

Comment: @FreeMan - I'd argue the heat has been more sustained, which brings its own issues. I suspect you were staying in a hotel, which has AC. The vast majority of northern european homes don't. Our flat, in an old building with thick walls, is comfortable without AC, for the first week of heat. After that, it gets increasingly unpleasant. I've stayed in the midwest - you guys are big fans of the whole "freezer-like air conditioning"

Comment: @FreeMan probably to be put on the account of ignorance? Many records where beaten this year, of high heat, amount of forest burnt, lack of water... This is causing serious suffering, and so, yes, I don't think it's a very nice thing to find amusing. Do you find it amusing as well when people freeze in snow storms in Texas? Or do you have more compassion towards your countrymen?

Comment: @njzk2 I don't find it amusing that people freeze in snowstorms in places where they aren't used to it, but I do find it somewhat amusing when they talk about 2 inches of snow as if it's the absolute end of the world and the entire city all but shuts down. If something seems absolutely normal and common to you, hearing other people talk about it as if it's completely unheard-of and Absolutely Impossible to Deal With, it can be amusing. And I know people from more-northern areas making fun of my area for making a big deal about a mere foot or two of snow.

Comment: Europe with its housing designs is incomparable to wasteful America where people run AC’s throughout their entire house, sometimes even when they’re not at home. I live in a tropical country nowadays and I can take the heat very well, just to avoid the counter ‘you’re just not used to it’.

Comment: Not to mention taking a car everywhere instead of cycling or walking

Comment: Being "amused" by something that has killed people is generally considered insensitive, yes.

Comment: @Esther - the reason -10 or +40°C can both cause so much trouble [apart from the general population not being prepared for it] is that much infrastructure, roads, railways etc can only be built to a certain temperature tolerance, typically 40°C between extremes. Railways can only take so much heat before they bend - so making them OK to 50° [which is what they would reach on a hot summer's day in the UK, whilst the air temperature is 30] means they'll then stress at -5. Same for tarmac, etc. You have to pick a zone.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek the cars are more because in some areas, everything is just super far. But I live in NYC, and don't even own a car, but rather walk or take public transport (just because everything is close enough that a car isn't really necessary).

Comment: @Esther ok, but the end-result is that people, besides a few large cities which are mostly colder, are mostly in airconditioned cars instead of on a bicycle or walking. And that they are in airconditioned indoors for the rest of the time. So the situation is not comparable with Europe, especially with the housing where having even a single bedroom AC installed is rare. I live at 30+ degrees Celcius and don’t use an aircon at home because the house is built for it in my tropical country of residence. Back home that would be madness.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek yes I don't think I would handle 30+ degrees with no AC for any significant amount of time :)

Comment: This is a good answer to be honest. All the recommendations are great and sensible. The only reason for the downvotes is probably the opening paragraph.. It's not true that temperatures are the same as 3 years ago, this year has seen all-time (that includes 3 years ago) record highs across Europe, and heat waves lasting longer than before too.